# UITableViewController with a separate data source object

Tags: ios, datasource, tableview

I have a separate object for the data source of a UITableViewController. I want to modify the data source dynamically but I don't want to have a direct reference of the tableView object inside the data source. How can I notify the controller about the changes in the data source?

Currently I use the notification center but I don't believe this is the right choice.

Comment: What is modifying the data source? Why is it not the view controller?

Comment: I used the example from this [link](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/lighter-view-controllers.html). The data source is updated by a background service, that sends a notification.

Comment: I see noting wrong with using notifications for this purpose.

Comment: @rokjarc, notifications should be for broadcasting event information to unknown recipients. That could be the case here but unlikely. A direct reference to the table view is better from a knowledge / responsibility point of view.

Comment: Seems like a lot of extra work. How many VC do you have in your app?

Comment: @MihaiPopa, usually the view controller would be detecting the changes in the model, driving them into your data source and then reloading.

Comment: @Wain, I want the data source to handle all the logic related to model changes and I would like the view controller to only update the views.

Comment: @Wain: this is not necessary true from code reusability perspective. One solution would be that datamodel initiates notification and datasource (linked with table) is the receiver of it - but again: notifications are a good way to notify the table (or datasource) that view should be refreshed. And more views (possibly added later) could register to follow this notifications.

Comment: @rokjarc, the question is about dataSource->tableView, not model->dataSource. model broadcasting change events is suitable. dataSource is already tied to the table view by its very nature so notification is not suitable here.

Comment: @Wain: i get your point. But: yes and no. dataSource is not necessarily directly tied to a single table - it can serve multiple tables. Though your answer is definitely correct code reusability is sacrificed here. It could be just the matter of "coding preferences" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be appropriate to give the data source a reference to the table view to be refreshed or to add a property which is a block that the data source calls when some data has been updated (this block is supplied by the view controller and just reloads the table view).

The block approach is a little more generic and allows your data source to more easily be used with table / collection views.

In both cases, the relationship you're looking at is direct and 1 to 1. This is not a suitable place to use notifications. Notifications are for non-direct, broadcast type 1 to many communication requirements.

Comment: I think that creating a block property is the right approach. It is the same approach used by the guys from objc.io to configure the cells.

Answer (score 3):

It is ok to send an `NSNotification` telling the `UITableView` that the model has changed, read the data again and reload the table.

Answer (score 0):

I got struct at the thing, One alternative I fount was KVO but I did not get much success implementing KVO, So I am also thinking to use Block. And you preferred which approach ?